# SqlException inside TransactionScope

Tags: vb.net, exception, .net-2.0, transactionscope

I'm currently working on a legacy project in VB.NET 2.0.
The project has a very funny DAL-layer which does not incorporate transactions :-|
Anyway, it's my job to make some parts of the program transactional and I don't
have access to the DAL layer code.
So I'm trying to put entire sections of code inside single TransactionScope.

Now here's the problem:
When an SqlException is thrown from somewhere deep down in the DAL layer, my transaction always gets rolled back! Even if I catch and handle the exception inside that same TransactionScope.

My question: Is this normal behaviour?
and is there anything I can do about this?

I think it's normal that the transaction is rolled back when an exception gets thrown beyond the bounds of the TransactionScope, but not if the exception is handled within those bounds!

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit: The SqlException is actually thrown from within a System.Data.Common.SqlCommand, so I can't really stop it from occurring.**

Regards,
ldx

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am going to retract the answer I had below, which I've edited out to avoid confusing anyone more than neccessary... :)

After more testing, I determined that if normal exceptions are caught and handled (not re-thrown) the transaction would completed as expected. It may be that certain classes of exceptions (such as sql exceptions participating in that transaction) may always invalidate the transactions in the root scope even if handled, but I haven't tested that so can't confirm that theory.

Sorry!

> Yes, this does seem to be by design. From the transactionScope documentation:
>
> [snip wrong information]